# How to write a Postgres language handler using MSVC

Tags: postgresql, visual-c++, postgresql-extensions

Here is the code, straight out of the sample. 64 bit install, x64 build.

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"
#include "commands/trigger.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "access/heapam.h"
#include "utils/syscache.h"
#include "catalog/pg_proc.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif


PGDLLEXPORT Datum plsample_call_handler(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS); // <-- the answer!!


PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(plsample_call_handler);

Datum
plsample_call_handler(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  Datum          retval;
  retval = 42;
  return retval;
}
```

It compiles and links OK. Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION plsample_call_handler() RETURNS language_handler
    AS 'TryPostgresPl.dll'
    LANGUAGE C;
CREATE LANGUAGE plsample
    HANDLER plsample_call_handler;
```

And here is the error message.

```
ERROR: could not find function "plsample_call_handler" in file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/TryPostgresPl.dll"
SQL state: 42883
```

So near and yet so far. Really no idea where to look.

---

Edited to show the answer as per Nick Barnes. Note that a peek with depends.exe showed 2 exports previously, now 3.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Thanks! Spot on. Edited to show the answer. If you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it. BTW there are other things in that article -- excellent link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample in the Postgres docs is squarely targeted at Linux environments; apparently there's a bit more involved in Windows. There is [an excellent article](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) by [@CraigRinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) which explains how to go about it in Visual Studio.

In this case, it looks like you just need to add the following function prototype:

```
PGDLLEXPORT Datum plsample_call_handler(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
```

Comment: Solved my problem. It's still pretty nasty down there, but that was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me (Postgres 13 x64, VS2019, MSVC 14.27), it was enough to just add `PGDLLEXPORT` in front of `PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1`, i.e:

```
PGDLLEXPORT PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(my_func);
```

Looking closer, this expands to the equivalent of:

```
PGDLLEXPORT extern Datum my_func(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);
... plus a bunch more stuff
```

You'll notice that's very similar to what's being done manually in the accepted answer, so this way seems to avoid some duplication. The only difference is the `extern` keyword; to be honest I don't know enough about C to know why putting `PGDLLEXPORT` *before* `extern` is still valid (rather than after it as I see in all the examples), but the compiler doesn't complain and the extension works.

YMMV especially if these macros change in the future.

Comment: It just sneaks in a `__declspec (dllexport)` so it's not that surprising. Seems this issue of persuading MSVC to do the right exports is pretty well known now. Pioneers get arrows, settlers get paved roads.